# ServiceStack resolving\throwing 404 depending on the order of the methods in my IService?

Tags: servicestack

```
public class UgGroupEditorService : IService {
  public object Get(GroupsRequest request){}
  public object Post(GroupsRequest request){}
  public object Get(GroupsHelloRequest request)
    {
        return "Hey there";
    }
}
```

So regardless of the route, GroupsHelloRequest 404s here...

Now if I just cut GroupsHelloRequest out and move it up **above** Get(GroupsRequest..) it now properly returns "Hey there".

Now more than that the GroupsRequest GET just works everywhere in the class with no issues.

Am I just missing something here?

Comment: Can you put a stand-alone example that we can run to reproduce this issue on GitHub please?

Comment: I can try to find the time sure